# Unable to write entire <tr> in Cypress test script

Tags: cypress

I am trying to write <tr> elements found in a table to an external file. But unable to save the data.

```
const rows = []
cy.get('tbody').eq(2).within(() => {
  cy.get("tr").then((rows) => {
    rows.toArray().forEach((element) => {
        cy.log(element)
        rows.push(element)
      });
  });
});
cy.log(rows)
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/test.txt', rows)
```

The first cy.log() is printing the desired <tr> correctly. But the second cy.log() is printing the empty array. Also the file is empty. I also tried to write the element directly but no luck. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Output of cy.log(element) :

```
<tr class="altRow row1" id="country_list">
    <td>AAE</td> <td>ANNABA</td> <td>DZ</td> <td>ALGERIA</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the `tr` element using id. And then direct your search inside the same tr using `within`. Then using `each()` you can iterate over the `td` elements and then write the td inner texts(country names) in the txt file. The `flag: a+`makes sure that the new content is appended at the end of the file, so that with every write the file is not over-written.

```js
cy.get('tr#country_list').within(() => {
  cy.get('td').each(($ele) => {
    cy.log($ele.text()) //Prints the country names one by one
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/test.txt', $ele.text(), {flag: 'a+'}) //Adds the country in txt file
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response; unfortunately both solutions saving empty JSON tags to the file. {
    "0": {},
    "length": 1
  }
   The cy.log($ele) is printing the elements to console correctly (correct loop count as well).

Comment: I also tried the binary mode to avoid stringify, but still no luck. cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/test.txt', element, {encoding: null,flag: 'a+',})

Comment: Do you just want to get the tr texts  or the entire tr html element? And also add the html for the tr elements how it looks like

Comment: output added to the question.